# Running Multiple X11 Servers Simultaneously

Tags: display, catalina, x11

I used to run multiple X11 servers on different DISPLAYs with different Window Managers, but now I get a return code of 1 when starting a second X11 server (or startx hangs waiting for the X11 server to start). This apparently started with xorg-server 1.20.8. My previous version was 1.20.6 so I apparently missed a version, where this might have broken.

My OS is 10.15.5 Beta (19F62f) (which may be a problem).

Has anyone run multiple X11 servers with xorg-server 1.20.8 and Catalina (any version)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate /Applications/MacPorts/X11.app to another name, edit the other name's Content/Info.plist, change both “org.macports.X11” to another name.

Not sure changing both is necessary.

Comment: I'm always curious about X11 displays though I've never done it on macOS.  However, I can't tell if this is a comment, a follow-on to the question, or what... can you explain in further detail? Because I can't grasp the gist of this "answer."

Comment: Sorry, this was the answer to my own question.

If you have /Applications/MacPorts/X11.app (implying that you also have MacPorts installed), you can control-click on it in Finder and select “Duplicate” to make a copy of X11.app. Then you can edit (TextEdit, MacVim, nano, etc) the package's Content/Info.plist, change all “org.macports.X11” to something else, and be able to run both X11 applications simultaneously.

As to _why_ you'd want to do such a thing, well, in my case I wanted to show something with the native window manager “quartz-wm” but still have my own window manager and apps.